# Assign the return of two piped functions in bash to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I make a get request to a public API via the unix shell. Then I select a specific string value pair. This works perfectly, however I am unable to assign it to a variable called max_temperature.

Can someone help?

```
 response="$(curl $url)"
 max_temperature=$response |  jq '.["main"].temp_max'
```

Comment: `k=v | cmd` assigns `v` to `k` producing no output, then invokes `cmd` (with no input). Both operations run in a subshell (because of `|`) and the assignment is lost after the subshell ends

Comment: `max_temperature=$(curl "$url" | jq '.["main"].temp.max')` may be what you want

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
 max_temperature=$response |  jq '.["main"].temp_max'
```

will cause the `max_temparature` var to be set to the contents of `$response` and pipe the output of this statement (in this case no output) to jq.

What you probably want is:

```
max_temperature=$(echo $response | jq '.["main"].temp_max')
```

This spawns a subshell and executes

```
echo $response | jq '.["main"].temp_max'
```

in it.

However, since a subshell does not take its parents environment with it by default, `$response` will be empty when it is echoed. You will need to export it in the line before. Hence:

```
 response="$(curl $url)"
 export response 
 max_temperature=$(echo $response |  jq '.["main"].temp_max')
```

More on [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: I believe export is implicit inside `$()`: `a=b; bash -c 'echo $a'; echo $(echo "$a"|cat)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. One more question, why do I have to put " " around the command substitution at the response variable and not at the max_temperature one? Or doesn't it make a difference?

Comment: you should double-quote variable use to avoid glob expansion,etc: `echo "$response"`. Consider: `a='b /*'; echo $a`

Comment: @luke33 If in doubt, add double-quotes. Occasionally it's wrong but usually it isn't. See, for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary